# Upload laravel project on live

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How to upload larval project to server?

I have uploaded larval website which is perfectly working in local computer, but when I uploaded to server same like as I am uploading other PHP website, but it is not going to view it shows a blank screen.

Please let me know, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: check nginx\php-fpm\apache\laravel error logs

Answer (score 1):

Copy the .env file also or set the appkey as environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Did you install laravel in your server and make sure the php version and server environment are match as per the laravel 5.2 documentation

Answer (score 0):

Tips on deploying Laravel:

1. Make sure the server is pointing to public folder not the project folder

   - Change the `DocumentRoot` to pointed to `public` folder
   - Create a basic URL that return a view to test this first step
2. Change the `.env` accordingly. Few important values are:

   - Application key. Run `php artisan key:generate` if not available yet
   - Database configurations. (Host, port, username, password)
   - Environment key need to be set as `production`. This is not super crucial. It will still working but nice to do it to hide any insecure error messages

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions on the storage directory. The application need to be able to write to it.

You also need to look in the logs:

storage/logs/laravel.log

And look in your webserver error log.